# java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested

Tags: java, jdbc

The title is the problem I am having. Any ideas what will sort this? I have been playing around with this for the past 5 hours.

Here is my code and if you have any questions then let me know.

*ID is a global variable

```
 String UpdateFirst = txtFirstSettings.getText();
        String UpdateLast = txtLastSettings.getText();
        String UpdateSex = txtSexSettings.getText();
        String UpdateJobTitle = txtJobTitleSettings.getText();
        String UpdateEmail = txtEmailSettings.getText();
        String UpdateLawFirm = txtLawFirmSettings.getText();
        try {
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Lawyers";
            String uName = "spyfire14";
            String uPass = "spyfire14";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                   ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM LAWYERLISTS WHERE ID = " + ID;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                rs.first();
                    rs.updateString("FIRST_NAME", UpdateFirst);
                    rs.updateString("LAST_NAME", UpdateLast);
                    rs.updateString("SEX", UpdateSex);
                    rs.updateString("JOB_TITLE", UpdateJobTitle);
                    rs.updateString("EMAIL", UpdateEmail);
                    //Include a confirmation
                    rs.updateRow();
                    rs.close();
                    stmt.close();
                    System.out.println(UpdateEmail);
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("EMAIL"));

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Here is the full exception code:

```
Aug 31, 2018 5:18:10 PM dashboardapp.Home btnSaveSettingsMouseReleased
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ResultSet.updateRow(Unknown Source)
    at dashboardapp.Home.btnSaveSettingsMouseReleased(Home.java:1851)
    at dashboardapp.Home.access$600(Home.java:46)
    at dashboardapp.Home$6.mouseReleased(Home.java:365)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetPreparedStatement.readExecute_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ResultSet.readUpdateRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ResultSet.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ResultSet.updateRowX(Unknown Source)
    ... 36 more
```

EDIT: I did what the comments said, I know do not get a warning but it does not now actually change the database

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                   ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM LAWYERLISTS WHERE ID = " + ID;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                rs.first();
                    rs.updateString("FIRST_NAME", UpdateFirst);
                    rs.updateString("LAST_NAME", UpdateLast);
                    rs.updateString("SEX", UpdateSex);
                    rs.updateString("JOB_TITLE", UpdateJobTitle);
                    rs.updateString("EMAIL", UpdateEmail);
                    con.commit();
                    //Include a confirmation
                    //rs.updateRow();
                    rs.close();
                    stmt.close();
```

Comment: See if the following helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582682/a-lock-could-not-obtained-within-the-time-requested-issue

Comment: Already looked at that. That is why I have added the rs.close() and the stmt.close()

Comment: What happens if you use `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` instead? What happens if you add `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` before creating the statement and `connection.commit()` after updating? Also why don't you just use an update statement? As I suggested on your previous question, that is simpler and likely works better.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I now do not get a warning come up. However, it does not actually change the database at all. I have added an edit onto my post with my new code

Comment: That is because you need to call `rs.updateRow()` to actually update the row, and when you call it, you need to call it **before** `con.commit()`. But again, why can't you just use an update statement? Updating through a result set is a weird way of updating, it has a lot of overhead and complications. It is only really useful in interactive updating eg in a GUI application (and even then it is of questionable value). Executing a parameterized update statement is simpler and much better in almost all situation.

Comment: I am using a GUI which might explain why am I doing it this way